# Cannot find the docker container running on port 80, tried everything usual

Tags: macos, docker

What happened:
I ran a container (vuejs-build website on a httpd:2.4) from shell (oh my zsh) on mac OS 11.2.2 using the previous docker release.
Then I updated the mac OS docker desktop.
Now the container is running but it's not showing on docker ps -a or docker container ls -a. I cannot find the process no matter what I try. Tried all the ps aux commands with grep, all lsof -wahtever, finding it in activity tool on mac. Even restarting the mac or stopping docker deamon does not stop it.

Has anybody a clue how to find it? I can open and refresh the webpage that is running in the container.

Docker version now says: Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88.

PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: Are you sure that browser opens page from app from docker? because docker runs on VM (mac os does have linux kernel for container support), so if you stop docker desktop, you app should be stopped, probably, you forgot to close nodejs in background

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself:
The container was stuck but restart seemed to have actually killed it.
However:
I realized that assets such as images are not being loaded despite JS and CSS is.
So I tried starting another httpd instance with `docker run -p 80:80 httpd` and reloaded. Firstly the same site as before appeared. But being able to start another httpd got me thinking.
The I opened dev tools in my browser. That disables Cache (using Chrome). Another hit on refresh then showed the "It works" page from httpd.
Some researching gave me the following theory: Vuejs stores the compiled Markup, JS and CSS on your browsers persistence storage. Probably for performance.